# Find the most frequent but weighted values in Excel for a voting system calculator

Tags: excel

I'm looking to create a voting system calculator, by taking a list of people's preferences (1st to 5th preference), and automatically find the most popular ones, but by giving weight to the place of the user's preference.
i.e 1st Preference gets 5 points, 2nd Preference gets 4 points, 3rd preference gets 3 points etc.
Then add up the points values, and show the top 6 most popular ones based on this voting system.

I have followed [this post](https://www.exceldemy.com/find-most-frequent-numbers-excel/) for the most frequent numbers... but it's the weighting/boosting of values that I'm missing out on.
In my example, I will only have 4 or 5 people voting, and I have roughly 25 possible values.... so for now, the alphabet works pretty well. Here is an example of the results that I'm after.
[image: Voting System example]

*The results show the aggregate points of the most popular preferences, and the most popular preferences themselves in the two rows.
Now I manually figured out these results in a separate two columns on the side, but ideally I just get this all within the cells V3 to AA4...if that's possible, however I'm open to any better alternatives.

Here's my manual column calculation list to show how I know the preferences:-

[image: Manual Voting List]

Comment: is this for Office 365?

Comment: You can do this easily in Power Query, if that is an option

Comment: Yes, Office 365... but no, I won't be able to use Power Query.
At the moment I have these calculations going on 'off-screen' (i.e in hidden fields, or on another sheet). Maybe that's enough and a single-cell calculation would become unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

Just use SUMIF:

[image]

My formula in Y4:

```
=SUMIF($B$4:$U$4;X4;$B$3:$U$3)
```

Piece of cake.

Besides, if you got E365, with functions like UNIQUE and SORT probably you could do the whole list with formulas. In my example, Excel 2007, I had to manually input values A to Z.

Comment: Sorry if my question was confusing. I have already implemented SUMIF in the large list at the bottom. What I'm after is getting the top 6 from those, for both their Preference and Preference Value.

Comment: @SeanHolmesby My bad then, I understood wrong. Consider using Pivot Tables in your SUMIF dataset to filter the TOP5 values.

Comment: I'm also having multiple things being voted on (about 10 items to vote on)... and wanted 'Value and Pref' lines for each, one after the other. In order to do this, I have added a sheet for each vote, done SUMIF in a list on those sheets, and re-referenced them back in the Results on the original sheet.  Maybe this is better than trying to get a massive calculation all in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this by shifting all of the calculations off to another sheet, having one sheet per 'item being voted on'. Then taking the results from there and putting them back into the 'Results' cells for each item.

This allowed me to have rows for items being voted on, while 'hiding' the calculations away on the other sheets.

Thanks to @foxfire-and-burns-and-burns, on the other 'calculation' sheet I used SUMIF, referencing the main data sheet.

```
=SUMIF(MainVotesSheet!$B$4:$U$4;X4;MainVotesSheet!$B$3:$U$3)
```

[image: SUMIF Vote scoring]

Then I added some calculations to figure out the Ranks, Score and which Option got that Score.

[image: Calculations Scores]

Where, 'Score Result' is

```
=LARGE(B$2:B$29,D3)
```

where D3 is the Rank number I'm after.

And 'Option' will find that one in the list of SUMIFs using an index to match. This equation also allows for Options that have equalling votes.

```
=IF(E2>0, INDEX(A$2:A$29, MATCH(1, (B$2:B$29=LARGE($B$2:$B$29,D2)) * (COUNTIF(F$1:F1, A$2:A$29)=0), 0)), "")
```

Then I have the results I'm after, but because I wanted to move it into a single row, I go back to my 'MainVotesSheet', and reference these cells.

1st Place Score

```
=Item1Calcs!$E$2
```

1st Place Option

```
=Item1Calcs!$F$2
```

[image: Final Result]

Now, the only thing left is adding rows for each Item to Vote on....
In which case, Calculation Sheets needed to be duplicated, with the SUMIF referencing the appropriate row from the MainVotesSheet.
And then, each of the Results in the MainVotesSheet needed to reference it's corresponding Calculations Sheet.

This was a bit of a hassle manually updating it... and I'm sure it's not the cleanest solution, but it works, and will hopefully help anyone looking to do something similar.